# PHP print all values returned using While Loop and Arrays

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am having problem with the following code which is returning only last 1 record.

Using while loop I am able to retrieve all the values and add it to arrays and get it over for each loop but I am unable to return all the values.

Upon calling this function is only returning last 1 record. Can anyone please help me fix this code in a way that it will return all the values. Thanks

```
echo gettradinghours("54");
function gettradinghours($storeid){

  $select_tradinghours = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM `tradinghours` where `storeid`='54' ORDER BY FIELD(openday, 'MONDAY', 'TUESDAY', 'WEDNESDAY', 'THURSDAY', 'FRIDAY', 'SATURDAY', 'SUNDAY');");

 $atradinghours = array();
 while($fetch_tradinghours = mysqli_fetch_array($select_tradinghours)){
     array_push($atradinghours, $fetch_tradinghours['openday']. ' ' .$fetch_tradinghours['starttime']. ' - ' .$fetch_tradinghours['endtime']);
  }
  foreach($atradinghours as $atradinghoursr){
       $getval = $atradinghoursr;
  }

  return $getval;
}
```

Comment: Yes you are returning the value after foreach loop completed so it returns last value in $atradinghours  array

Comment: @lock,I have posted answer of your question you just need to add brackets in forloop of $getval. so it would be $getval[] instead of $getval & your problem will be resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First thing to point out is that `mysqli_query()`'s first argument is you need to feed it with a mysqli connection.
- Second, you do not need another foreach loop. Just push the values inside the while and then finally in the end return that value container.

```
function gettradinghours($storeid){
    // 1st point! connection!
    $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'database_base');
    $select_tradinghours = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM `tradinghours` WHERE `storeid`='54' ORDER BY FIELD(openday, 'MONDAY', 'TUESDAY', 'WEDNESDAY', 'THURSDAY', 'FRIDAY', 'SATURDAY', 'SUNDAY')");

    $atradinghours = array();
    // no need for that array push thing, just push it normally and return in the end
    while($fetch_tradinghours = mysqli_fetch_array($select_tradinghours)){
         $atradinghours[] = $fetch_tradinghours['openday']. ' ' .$fetch_tradinghours['starttime']. ' - ' .$fetch_tradinghours['endtime'];
    }
    return $atradinghours; // return the gathered/pushed values
}

print_r(gettradinghours("54")); // use the function
```

- Lastly your parameter that you feed inside your function is not used. And use prepared statements instead.

```
function gettradinghours($storeid){

    // connection!
    $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'database_base');
    // use prepared statements!
    $stmt = $connection->prepare("
        SELECT openday, starttime, endtime FROM `tradinghours` WHERE`storeid` = ? 
        ORDER BY FIELD(openday, 'MONDAY', 'TUESDAY', 'WEDNESDAY', 'THURSDAY', 'FRIDAY', 'SATURDAY', 'SUNDAY')
    ");
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $storeid); // bind the paramter input!
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($openday, $starttime, $endtime);

    $atradinghours = array();
    while($stmt->fetch()) { // as usual push the values
        $atradinghours[] = $openday. ' ' .$starttime. ' - ' .$endtime;
    }

    return $atradinghours; // return the gathered values
}

print_r(gettradinghours(54));
```

Sidenote:

If you do not want such result (an array) you could build a string instead:

```
$atradinghours = '';
while($stmt->fetch()) { // as usual push the values
    $atradinghours .=  $openday. ' ' .$starttime. ' - ' .$endtime . '<br/>';
}
```

Then in the end, you could now echo properly a string:

```
echo gettradinghours(54);
```

Comment: rning: mysqli_stmt::bind_result(): Number of bind variables doesn’t match number of fields in prepared statement

Comment: @lock i was making some revisions, check out the answer again

Comment: Output returned as "Array"

Comment: @lock yes, thats an array, use `var_dump()/print_r()` to see the contents

Comment: Awesome, I can see the output using print_r() but the problem is I don't want output in array format, I need output is just string format.

Comment: @lock yes you could make them as string instead, here is my suggestion. check my edit

Comment: Mate, you finally brought me all the way to begining. I know my code is correct but missing small `.` in before the `=` I forgot that `.` infront of `=` and tried lots of things. Anyways, thanks a ton mate.

Comment: @lock yes you need a `.` to concatenate continually when you're inside the loop. sure man im glad i was able to helped.

Answer (score 2):

( 1 ) Return Array :

```
function gettradinghours($storeid){
                $getval = array();
                $select_tradinghours = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM `tradinghours` where `storeid`='54' ORDER BY FIELD(openday, 'MONDAY', 'TUESDAY', 'WEDNESDAY', 'THURSDAY', 'FRIDAY', 'SATURDAY', 'SUNDAY');");

               $atradinghours = array();
               while($fetch_tradinghours = mysqli_fetch_array($select_tradinghours)){
                     array_push($atradinghours, $fetch_tradinghours['openday']. ' ' .$fetch_tradinghours['starttime']. ' - ' .$fetch_tradinghours['endtime']);
                }
                foreach($atradinghours as $atradinghoursr){
                     $getval[] = $atradinghoursr;
                }
       return $getval;
    }
```

( 2 ) Return String :

```
function gettradinghours($storeid){
                $getval = '';
                $select_tradinghours = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM `tradinghours` where `storeid`='54' ORDER BY FIELD(openday, 'MONDAY', 'TUESDAY', 'WEDNESDAY', 'THURSDAY', 'FRIDAY', 'SATURDAY', 'SUNDAY');");

               $atradinghours = array();
               while($fetch_tradinghours = mysqli_fetch_array($select_tradinghours)){
                      $getval.= $fetch_tradinghours['openday']. ' ' .$fetch_tradinghours['starttime']. ' - ' .$fetch_tradinghours['endtime'];
                }

       return $getval;
    }
```

Comment: output is echoed as "Array" :(

Comment: Did you mean,you didn't get an array ? You can print_r(YOUR RETURN ARRAY) not use echo for array !

Comment: The output itself is printed as "Array".

Comment: $valuesArray = gettradinghours(storeid);
print_r($valuesArray);

Comment: Please kindly try as above comment,you can get your expected result.

Comment: yep, this works but I don't want the values in array format. i need values to be in string format.

Comment: Which values you want to access from array ? Access that value. Very simple. If My answer helps you to resolve your problem then please accept my answer.

Comment: Check it my answer now,I have edited my answer as per your requirement.If My answer helps you to resolve your problem then please accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why again an foreach

```
function gettradinghours($storeid){
            $select_tradinghours = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM `tradinghours` where `storeid`='54' ORDER BY FIELD(openday, 'MONDAY', 'TUESDAY', 'WEDNESDAY', 'THURSDAY', 'FRIDAY', 'SATURDAY', 'SUNDAY');");

           $atradinghours = array();
           while($fetch_tradinghours = mysqli_fetch_array($select_tradinghours)){
                 array_push($atradinghours, $fetch_tradinghours['openday']. ' ' .$fetch_tradinghours['starttime']. ' - ' .$fetch_tradinghours['endtime']);
            }

   return $atradinghours;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looping through the array and returning the last array element,

Where as you want whole array.

```
foreach($atradinghours as $atradinghoursr){
                 $getval = $atradinghoursr;
            }
```

Should only be

```
$getval = $atradinghours;
return $atradinghours;
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is in `$getval` you are just storing the last element,

you will need to make this an array also, `push()` in all elements like how you did in the while loop

and return the array

or just return the `$atradinghours` which is all the data anyway